# Running bat file in java not working

Tags: java, batch-file, runtime, disassembly, otool

I am trying to make a program to decompile a binary

this is my current code:

```
 try {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("Dumps.bat");
        out.println("@title Dumping");
        out.println("\\Developer\\usr\\bin\\otool -tV " + BFText.getText().toString() + " > " + RFText.getText().toString());
        out.println("@pause");
        out.println("@exit");
        out.close();
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            rt.exec("cmd /c start Dumps.bat");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Unfortunately, it created the bat file but tool doesn't seem to be creating the Results File

BFText is a textfield for the user to type the name of the binary
RSText is a textfield for the user to type the name of the text file which will be created by tool

By the way, i am using a mac, is that a problem? If so, what kind of code should i use instead?

Comment: Have you tried giving the full path to Dumps.bat in the rt.exec command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Mac, you can't use batch files, but you can try using command files:  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2375724?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: What would my shell script contain? "#!/bin/bash" and "otool -tV BFText.getText() > RFText/getText()" ?

Comment: I figured it out myself. Thanks!

Comment: How do I command the program to run it? "cmd /c start test.command" does not work

Answer (score 1):

You can't run batch files on a Mac. Batch files are local to Windows only. This is your problem.